# How do I clear the image cache after editing an image on my site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using an outside page to update an image in my system. When I'm redirected back to the page I've worked in, I still see the old picture. I don't see my changes until I press ctrl+f5. Is their any way to redirect with history delete or any other solution?

Comment: You should fix your cache headers.

Comment: @SLaks - The problem with cache headers is that you need to know the TTYL for the image when you serve it the first time. If you set it too low, you'll keep re-requesting the file just to get a 304 back. For this type of scenario, I prefer timestamping the URL as mentioned below.

Comment: @James: Only if you can generate good timestamps.  Otherwise, you'll keep re-requesting the same file and _not_ getting a 304.  You're right that timestamps are better where possible.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes, you need reliable timestamps to prevent the URL from changing when the file contents doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a query string to your image source, it will prevent the browser from caching it. Some people use the date, I prefer the GUID

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
string GuidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
GuidString = GuidString.Replace("=", "");
GuidString = GuidString.Replace("+", "");

Image1.ImageUrl = "/path/to/new/image.jpg?r=" + GuidString;
```

It will end up making your image source look similar to this:

```
 <img src="/path/to/image.jpg?r=Vqad3W8ZUG6oXgFzZIw" id="Image1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will force the browser to re-request the image even if it hasn't changed. You are preventing all caching, which I don't think is what the OP intends.

Comment: you are great man, i was facing this issue from last two days and it finally solved my problem :)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The decision to refresh or not is up to the browser. A standard technique for solving this is to add a timestamp to your images. For example:

```
<img src='/images/foo.jpg?ts=1'/>
```

When you update the image, send back:

```
<img src='/images/foo.jpg?ts=2'/>
```

The browser will see two different URL and request the image again. You can use a timestamp (last modified time of the file), a hash of the file contents, an incrementing integer, ... Anything to change the URL and force the browser to reload.

N.B. When serving static files, web servers will ignore the query string. So you don't need any code running to implement this. This technique also works well for any content that you want to force a refresh on including CSS, JS, ...

Answer (score 0):

in C# there is a much simpler way.  you set the bitmapimage CreateOptions to BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache and it forces the image to load from file instead of using existing cache.

```
        var bi = new BitmapImage();

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filepath);
        const uint requestedSize = 400;
        const ThumbnailMode thumbnailMode = ThumbnailMode.PicturesView;
        const ThumbnailOptions thumbnailOptions = ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail;

        StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(thumbnailMode, requestedSize, thumbnailOptions);

        bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        bi.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
        bi.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
        bi.SetSource(thumbnail);
        return bi;
```